# Identify whether a record has many products

Tags: ms-access, powerbi, powerpivot, powerquery

I am using both Access and Power BI to solve this but to no avail. 
In principle it actually is quite simple but I need to do it in a particular way for subsequent pricing calculations.

Essentially, I have a table with transactions with service id. This service id will appear multiple times with one or multiple products. If it is just one product then I need to populate a column with "Single Product" otherwise "Multiple Product". See below for an illustration :

```
Serviceid  Product  Type
1          A        Multiple Products
1          B        Multiple Products
2          A        Single Product
3          A        Single Product
3          A        Single Product
3          A        Single Product
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Power BI, you can do this within Power Query:

```
let
    Source = SourceTable,
    fnDistinct = (MyTable, MyServiceid) =>
        let
            #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(MyTable, each ([Serviceid] = MyServiceid)),
            #"Distinct Products" = List.Count(List.Distinct(#"Filtered Rows"[Product]))
        in
            #"Distinct Products",
    #"Added M Type" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "M Type", each if fnDistinct(Source, [Serviceid]) > 1 then "Multiple Products" else "Single Product", type text)
in
    #"Added M Type"
```

Or using DAX:

```
DAX Type = 
VAR CountProducts = 
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( Table1[Product] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[Serviceid] )
    )
RETURN
    SWITCH ( 
        CountProducts,
        1, "Single Product",
        "Multiple Products"
    )
```

Worked example PBIX file: https://pwrbi.com/so_55918190/

Performance testing DAX solution, on 250,000 rows:

[image]

Comment: This worked a treat. Thanks so much! Also thanks for formatting my table.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work in a file with 200,000 rows. It just keeps calculating and increasing the file size

Comment: Did you try the DAX code, as a calculated column? Works pretty quickly, on a test data set of 250k rows. The Power Query option will be slow with large volumes of data.

Comment: OK, just tried the DAX measure but I only see "Single Products" so, somewhere the formula isn't working. My table has more columns fyi.

Comment: The context of the other columns will be affecting the result, in this case. I've edited the code, to allow for other columns (`ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[Serviceid] )`)

Comment: Hey Olly, how have you learnt power pivot and query? I'm making slow progress but i want to find better resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IIF()` with `EXISTS` to populate the new column

```
select
  t.serviceid,
  t.product,
  iif(
    exists (
      select 1 from tablename where serviceid = t.serviceid and product <> t.product
    ),
    'Multiple Products',
    'Single Product'
  ) as type
from tablename as t
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple subquery:

```
Select 
    Serviceid,
    Product,
        IIf((Select Count(*) 
        From  YourTable As T
        Group By Serviceid, Product
        Having T.Serviceid = YourTable.Serviceid And T.Product = YourTable.Product) = 1, "Single Product", "Multiple Products") As [Type]
From
    YourTable
Group By
    Serviceid,
    Product
```

Comment: Thanks will give it a go.